# Custom SQLExceptionConverter using hibernate 5.1

Tags: java, hibernate

In our application we have a custom sql exception converter. After the migration from an older version of hibernate to 5.1 it stopped working. It is configured in hibernate.xml as :

```
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.sql_exception_converter">com.ourapp.common.CustomHibernateExceptionConverter</prop>
```

I don't know why but the default one is always used

```
org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter
```

I've tried to change the content of our custom converter, even using the same content as the default converter but it does not seems to being picked up.
If someone encountered this problem thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: In case you opened https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11862 you need to provide a test case.